# is this an example of nominal unification?

Tags: unification

I am thinking that is the following a problem solved by nominal unification.

$\lambda a.X = \lambda b.\lambda c.c $

where we find $X$. The answer is obvious.

The reason is that it seems in nominal unification $X$ always will be an atom, not a function such as $\lambda c.c$.
The theory seems works fine with this input, just did not saw any example similar to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, these unify under nominal unification.  You get a unifier like $X = (b\ a)\bullet\lambda c.c$ which simplifies to $X = \lambda c.c$.  Figures 1 and 3 of [Nominal Unification](http://gabbay.org.uk/papers/nomu-jv.pdf) describe the relevant details of the algorithm.  In particular the transitions will be $\approx?$-abstraction-2 and $\approx?$-variable followed by $\#?$-abstraction-2 and $\#?$-atom.